# How to show a diff for a given SVN revision

Tags: diff, git-svn

I am using `git-svn` and I would like to show the changes that were introduced by a certain SVN revision.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

#### Manual way

1. Convert the revision number to a Git hash:

```sh
git svn find-rev r1234
```

2. Show a diff to the previous commit (replace `thehash` with the output from previous command):

```sh
git diff thehash^..thehash
```

#### Using git alias

You can get it all in one with this git alias.

1. Edit `~/.gitconfig` (section `[alias]`), by adding the line

```
sdiff = "!f() { r=r"$(echo $1 | tr -d 'r')"; h="$(git svn find-rev $r)"; echo $r=${h}; git diff ${h}^..${h} ; } ; f ${1}"
```

2. Get the diff for a specific revision by using either of the following syntaxes:

```sh
git sdiff 1234
git sdiff r1234
```

Notice how the alias also prints the correspondence between revision number and hash. If you don't like that, remove the part `echo $r=${h};`